# Is there a way to get Flash Builder to update/re-copy a non-embedded file in bin-debug?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I've slightly modified the index.template.html to include an external CSS file, which is also in the html-template directory. **When I make changes to the CSS file, the newer version does not get copied over unless I do a Project > Clean Project... every time.**

This gets very tedious, so I'm wondering if there any thing I can do to make it update, just as if I were editing index.template.html (which rebuilds the project automatically if edited).

FWIW, "Copy non-embedded files to output folder" is selected in the Project Settings. I even named my CSS file "main.template.css" and sure enough the name change happens when it's copied over. It's just that Flash Builder doesn't recognize when the file has been changed to automatically update the copy in the output folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to put the css file in the template folder. Create a new asset folder (or use an existing folder) and add it as an additional source in Actionscript Build Path (Project Properties).

Comment: I just did this and it worked. Thanks! Kind of weird to have to set it up that way, but it's a simple workaround.